# Learning in C - possible to write/read to a text file?

Tags: text

Hey I'm just learning C in school and I have this idea for a little mini programming project I want to do. I know you guys know your shit on here so I'm wondering if it's possible to read and write to a text file in C?

And if so, can someone direct me to a link or give me a little sample code of how to do that?

Comment: It is possible, and there are thousands of resources if you just take ten seconds to google for the answer.

Comment: No I understand that. But I'm not sure which way is the good way. Or the best approach, least problematic. That's why I came here to find out.

Comment: @Robsta: The "best" way depends on the problem to solve and the available APIs.

Comment: @DarkDust: Again, you can tell than I'm new. I didn't know that. :|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[C file I/O](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cfileio.html)
there you go